# Hosting .net Core 2.1 on IIS Access to the solution path is denied?

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.1

I have a .net core 2.1 web API set up on a dev server and it works perfectly fine however when i try to browse the site on the live server i get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'R:\SoftCatWebApi\ETL' is denied.
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.CreateFileReader(String fileName)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors, LogFactory logFactory)
   at NLog.LogFactory.LoadXmlLoggingConfiguration(String configFile)
   at NLog.LogFactory.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)
   at NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)
   at NLog.Web.AspNetExtensions.ConfigureNLog(IHostingEnvironment env, String configFileRelativePath)
   at ETL.Program.<>c.<BuildWebHost>b__1_0(WebHostBuilderContext hostingContext, IConfigurationBuilder config) in C:\SoftCat\Systems\SoftCatInternalWebApi\ETL\Program.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at ETL.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in C:\SoftCat\Systems\SoftCatInternalWebApi\ETL\Program.cs:line 22
   at ETL.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\SoftCat\Systems\SoftCatInternalWebApi\ETL\Program.cs:line 18
```

I have tried allot of different things, i have the application pool applied to the folder with all permissions and i have Anonymous Authentication enabled.

I have literally tried multiple suggestions on different forums but nothing seams to fix my problem.

Any suggestions?

If i run the dll from the CMD i get a diffrent error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Update:

If i click on any of the option in IIS manager, i get an error to web.config

Comment: does your live-webapp user have permission to access R disk. Actually, R:\SoftCatWebApi\ETL ?  I had very similar issue while running a python app on IIS, chaning the user solved my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by user? Is it not the application pool that needs access to this location, so IIS is able to access the solution through the app pool @ibrahimozgon

Comment: I mean Application Pool Identity. I will write the details in answer to add screenshots.

Comment: Which action did you want to call from server? Share us the action code.

Comment: I am not trying to call an action, i am trying to get the web app to host on IIS without showing the HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error @TaoZhou

Answer (score 3):

seems, your application pool Identity doesn't have permission to access your path.
Just to be sure, change pool identity with a user that has permission.

[image: Pool Identity]

[image: Custom Account]

Comment: I tried using my Admin Account that defiantly had permissions to read/write to see if the above would work but still no luck >.<

Comment: Indeed :), The weird thing is this all works on the dev server which is pretty much a replicate.